# php if-else failing

Tags: php

What is wrong with this if-else statement.

```
if((strlen($objectData['pss'] >= 8))AND(strlen($objectData['pss'] <= 20)))
{
  //do my bidding
}
else
{
  echo "String to short or to long";
}
```

Ultimately I am trying to find if the variable is greater than or equal to 8 chars while being under or equal to 20 chars. My test string is 11 char, and I am seeing string to short/to long. I've done similar to this in the past, so I dunno what I mucked up at the moment (maybe Im just to tired to realize it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (strlen($objectData['pss']) >= 8 && strlen($objectData['pss']) <= 20)
```

Comment: hah. I see what I did wrong between yours and mine.. wow, guess I am just that tired, thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((strlen($objectData['pss']) >= 8) and (strlen($objectData['pss']) <= 20))
{ 
  //do my bidding 
} 
else 
{ 
  echo "String to short or to long"; 
}
```

I have corrected you brackets

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are indeed "to tired".. You are basically counting the length of an expression instead of the string itself:

```
if((strlen($objectData['pss']) >= 8)AND(strlen($objectData['pss']) <= 20))
```